# Rolling out install to >1 VM

Tags: hyper-v, windows-server-2008-r2, automation

I am using Windows Server 2008 R2, VMM, and Hyper-V.

Is there any way to roll out an installation of an application and the same .properties file (for silent install) to all the VMs at once?

Comment: do you have 100's of vm's or less then a 100, sccm for the 100's of vms and psexec/wmic for the less then 100!

Comment: Do you have a lot of physical machines? How would you normally roll software out to them? Stop and think why you'd treat virtuals any differently from an automated rollout perspective than physicals. There may be a good reason, but nine times out of ten you can just treat them the same.

Answer (score 1):

[SCVMM](http://www.microsoft.com/systemcenter/virtualmachinemanager/) is not meant to configure or maintaining machine images; that's what [SCCM](http://www.microsoft.com/systemcenter/configurationmanager/) is for. SCVMM is for managing Hyper-V Hosts and the 'resources' they contain.

Comment: Hi, I mentioned SCVMM to just explain the environment I have. I am aware it is not at all designed for rolling out installs. :) SCCM I will look into.

Comment: My apologies, I misread the question as "how can SCVMM roll out a configuration". If you have access to SCCM, it's a slick tool for doing rollouts and maintaining configurations. Otherwise there's other options, including open source: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_open_source_configuration_management_software